# Aware UserControl when add it to a parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a `UserControl` in my `WinForms` project. I add some objects of this `UserControl` to a `FlowLayoutPanel` at run time using code.

I want when I add my first `UserControl` to `FlowLayoutPanel`, change its `BackColor`.

Is there any `event` for the `UserControl` to aware when add it to a parent control(something like `UserControlAddedToParent`)?

Comment: `Control.ParentChanged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are looking for [Control.ParentChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event

> This event is raised if the Parent property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction